# How can I hard coded comments area to be shown in particular pages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, comments

In my sites I use static page as a front page, and I did some other static pages to show some special static content (and embedded object) but this page sin particular I want to have the comment area shows.

My question is: how to enable comments -preferred hard code- in particular pages? at least having the same category?

I am using wordpress 4.1 and Avada Theme.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can disable the comments on over all website by going to settings discussion and then uncheck the box that says, allow people to comment on new articles. This will remove all the comments on new pages and posts (starting from now). Now when you create a new page/post click on the button on the top that says **"screen options"**. Check the box that says "discussion". Now you will have a new field in your post from where you can enable/disable the posts individually.

If you want to do it through the code, one way would be to create separate files for each page e.g page-contact.php, So when someone goes to the contact page, this file will be served, it can be a clone of page.php and just needs the comment part removed. Another way would be to goto page.php and wrap the comments code with a condition like

```
if(is_page('contact') || is_page('about')){
// code to show comments. Comments will be shown on contact and about page
}
```